# C#, converting a case statement to a yield statement

Tags: c#, yield, yield-return

I want to convert this statement to build a list of VM images to use in testing into something more elegant using the yield keyword, but the syntax is elluding me.

Desired end goal.

```cs
List<VmImages> images;
images[0] - WindowsServer2019
images[1] - WindowsServer2016
images[2] - RhelServer;
images[3] - OpenLogic;
```

Today the code looks like this:

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < LinuxVMs; i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            linuxDistros.Add(ConfigLoader.redHat);
            break;
        case 1:
            linuxDistros.Add(ConfigLoader.openLogic);
            break;
        case 2:
            linuxDistros.Add(ConfigLoader.suse);
            break;
        case 3:
            linuxDistros.Add(ConfigLoader.ubuntu);
            break;
    }
}
```

This feels like a good case to use the yield keyword to simplify the logic into something like this, where I call `GetLinuxVMs()` for x number of times, where X is the count of `LinuxVMs`.

```cs
private static IEnumerable<VmDistribution> GetLinuxVmDistros()
{
    yield return ConfigLoader.redHat;
    yield return ConfigLoader.openLogic;
    yield return ConfigLoader.suse;
    yield return ConfigLoader.canonical;
}
```

I'm not sure how to integrate this into my code, this is what I've tried:

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < LinuxVMs; i++)
{
    linuxDistros.Add(GetLinuxVmDistros());
}
```

Since I get an IEnum back from the `GetLinuxVmDistros` method every time, I am puzzled as to how this is supposed to work at all.

Comment: What is type of `linuxDistros` ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you need a loop and a switch statement to simply add 4 values to a list in the first place? That could've been 4 lines just the same. Maybe stick to that.

Comment: Your code as-is does not seem to align with your end goal

Comment: Careful, you may end op on [TheDailyWTF](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/Switched_on_Loops) :-)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing that article has me thinking that what I'm trying is a bad idea.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @HansKeﬆing and [16.5 years later](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/a-select-sample) I'm not sure if much progress has been made!

Comment: Oh, the [for-switch](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/switch-the-dropdown) pattern in the wild. Nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your stated "desired end goal"

```
List<VmImages> images = new() {
    WindowsServer2019,
    WindowsServer2016,
    RhelServer,
    OpenLogic
}
```

All the rest of the looping/finagling is just confusing the issue, IMHO

Answer (score 2):

`GetLinuxVmDistros()` will return an `IEnumerable<VmDistribution>` as per your definition.

It seems you want to add to a collection called `linuxDistros` another collection.

If `linuxDistros` is a `List<VmDistribution>`, simply use the `AddRange` method:

```cs
linuxDistros.AddRange(GetLinuxVmDistros());
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-6.0

But I fail to see the point of creating an Enumerable just for this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain what you try to achieve since the naming is .. not clear. But with this code below, it works:

```cs
class ConfigLoader
{
    static public VmDistribution redHat { get; set; } = VmDistribution.a;
    static public VmDistribution openLogic { get; set; } = VmDistribution.b;
    static public VmDistribution suse { get; set; } = VmDistribution.c;
    static public VmDistribution canonical { get; set; } = VmDistribution.d;
}

enum VmDistribution { a, b, c, d }
IEnumerable<VmDistribution> GetLinuxVmDistros()
{
    yield return ConfigLoader.redHat;
    yield return ConfigLoader.openLogic;
    yield return ConfigLoader.suse;
    yield return ConfigLoader.canonical;
}

var list = new List<VmDistribution>();
list.AddRange(GetLinuxVmDistros());
```

Notice that in the end I'm invoking `GetLinuxVmDistros()` only once, and the list is filled with method `list.AddRange()`.

Comment: If I wanted to call GetLinuxVmDistros twice, wouldn't I get two IEnums back?  Are these not intended to be used in a for or foreach loop like I'm doing?

Comment: Well, when you call `list.AddRange( IEnumerable<> );`, what will happen in behind, that `IEnumerable` will be enumerated element by element and all of them will be added to the list. If You do that in that loop (`for`, `while`, ..), you will do it multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you should do whatever you need to do with the items with the loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < LinuxVMs; i++)
{
    ProcessItem(LinuxVMs[i]);
}
```

Having said that, there's isn't much point in yielding on such a small set of results.  The main purpose of `yield return` is to allow a large collection to be returned 1 item at a time, where the calling code may want to stop iterating over the items at any point.  Another usage is where fetching all items at once may be very expensive resource-wise.

For example, you may not want to continue if 1 item couldn't be processed for whatever reason.

```
for (var i = 0; i < LinuxVMs; i++)
{
    var result = ProcessItem(LinuxVMs[i]);
    
    if (!result.Success)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

However, if you just need the items in a list then forget all of that and just create the list with the items in it straight away:

```
var images = 
    new List<VmImages> 
    {
        WindowsServer2019,
        WindowsServer2016,
        RhelServer,
        OpenLogic
    };
```